# is saving another model through a foreign key possible? django

Tags: python, django, model, save, django-queryset

please ignore any typos, I am wondering if saving through a foreign key would work.  If it does, how do you do it though?

Let's say I have two models.

```
class TestOne(models):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    viewed = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class TestTwo(models):
    one = models.ForeignKey(TestOne)
    test = models.Charfield(max-length=100)
```

I know that with `ForeignKey`, I can access into `TestOne` and get the info but is there anyway I can save it too?

For example:

```
two = TestTwo.objects.get(pk=1)
two.test = "this is just a test"
two.one.viewed += 1
two.save()
```

For above, I know in TestTwo's test field will be saved but TestOne's viewed will not be incremented but is this possible, so I don't have to make another query and another save?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Of cause you can do `two.one.save()`.

Comment: @KlausD. Omg that's so true! Why didn't I think of it! THX THX

Comment: I also suggest you to add a helper method to `TestTwo` (such as `update_viewed()`) that increments the `viewed` value and then saves the instance. You can then simply call `two.update_viewed()`.